# Interfaces as parameters

Tags: c#, interface

In what scenarios would somebody pass (or receive) an interface as a parameter? Is it really a useful thing or just a fancy way of doing something?

Comment: I am quite new to C#, so some answers went above my head.:-) Sorry about that, but just trying to build my basic concepts.

In light of your answers and based on what I have read about interfaces, am I right in saying in simple terms, that by passing interfaces as paramaters, we are allowing that we can pass any (and only those) objects to a method that implements that interface. Like in the below example (IAnimal), we can pass any animal to the MakeNoise method, provided it implements IAnimal.

Comment: Yes, an interface basically represents a set of functionality implemented by a class. When you write your method to accept an interface as a parameter, what this means is that the method will take any object of a type that implements that interface. In the `IAnimal` example, the `IAnimal` interface guarantees a method called `MakeNoise`, so a method that accepts an `IAnimal` as a parameter can call `MakeNoise` on that parameter regardless of its underlying type.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's an **extremely** useful thing.

Take *any* of the [LINQ extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods.aspx), for instance. They don't care what's passed to them, as long as it implements `IEnumerable<T>`. The idea is that they can all be applied to anything that you can enumerate over using a `foreach` loop.

Imagine how pointlessly restrictive it would be if they all required you to pass `T[]` arrays, or `List<T>` objects, for example.

---

Here's just one very trivial illustration. Let's pretend the LINQ extensions don't exist (which is actually a real possibility if I'm using .NET 2.0) and I want to write a `Sum` method.

I could write it like this:

```
public static double Sum(List<double> values)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    foreach (double value in values)
    {
        sum += value;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

That's all well and good, but notice something here: I wrote the method to take a `List<double>`, which is a class that has **far more functionality than this code depends on**. Where does it use `Insert`? Where does it use `RemoveAt`? `FindAll`? `Sort`? Nope, none of that is required. So is it really *necessary* that this method get passed a `List<double>`?

Moreover, say I have a `double[]`. Theoretically, I should be able to pop that right in as the `values` parameter, since all I'm doing is enumerating over it using a `foreach`; but since I've typed `values` as `List<double>`, to pass a `double[]` to my `Sum` method I'd have to do this:

```
double sum = Sum(new List<double>(myArray));
```

That's just a completely unnecessary new object I've constructed simply to call code that really should've been able to handle my original object in the first place.

By writing methods that take interfaces as parameters, you make your code more flexible and more powerful, and you avoid imposing inappropriate restrictions (*give me an X, even though I could just as easily do this with a Y*) on calling code.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to remember, is that it's all about programming to the interface, not the implementation. Say for instance, I have a method where I want to do something, e.g.

```
public void MakeNoise(IAnimal animal)
{
  animal.MakeNoise();
}
```

I don't care what the specific implementation is, I just know that whatever is passed in, I can call MakeNoise(). I program to an interface, not an implementation.

```
public class Dog : IAnimal
{
  public void MakeNoise()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Woof");
  }
}

public class Cat : IAnimal
{
  public void MakeNoise()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Meow");
  }
}
```

Interface programming is a core aspect of OOP, you'll find them incredibly useful.

Comment: Because you're programming only to the interface choose their names carefully. INoiseMaker may be more appropriate in this case. That way it will be natural for other classes to implement the interface, i.e. JetPlane, FireCracker, or SmallChild.

Comment: @Dave M, very good point, interfaces (contracts) should be descriptive of their use.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you need abstraction.

One good example is the `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>` interfaces in the .NET Framework. They allow you to write Extension Methods that can be used against `List<T`>, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, or even `T[]`.

You could also take Dependency Injection for example. In ASP.NET MVC, it is common to use Repositories for Data Access:

```
public class MyClassRepository
{
    public MyClass GetById(int id)
    {
        // Some Implementation
    }
}

public class MyController
{
    private MyClassRepository _repo;

    public class MyController() : base(new MyClassRepository()) { }

    public class MyController(MyClassRepository repo) { _repo = repo; }
}
```

Now, if you want to Mock that Repository for Unit Testing...you're boned. There's no easy way. In comes Interfaces!

```
public interface IMyClassRepository
{
    public MyClass GetById(int id);
}

public class MyClassRepository : IMyClassRepository
{
    public MyClass GetById(int id)
    {
        // Some Implementation
    }
}

public class MyController
{
    private IMyClassRepository _repo;

    public class MyController() : base(new MyClassRepository()) { }

    public class MyController(IMyClassRepository repo) { _repo = repo; }
}
```

Now with the introduction of an Interface, we are free to mock IMyClassRepository however we see fit for testing purposes. Usually this involves a simple mock object with specified behavior to product reliable results.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces are very useful.

They help with decoupling your code - for example, if you use the `IList` interface and pass that in to your method and use it in your method, you can pass in *any* collection that implements this interface, whether it is in the BCL or not.

Answer (score 1):

One area where interfaces would make good sense is if you are using a [design pattern approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29).

For instance, the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), or the [Proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern), the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), and others.  You probably could choose not to use an interface, but I'd imagine that you'll quickly decide that the code becomes much cleaner (as in more modular, concerns-separated) than a non-interfaced code.  It just helps promote better code, in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism!

They help you write code that doesn't discriminate against certain classes just because they don't inherit from a special base class.  Your functions will be equal-opportunity executors.